# Excluir periodo sem tag Between

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Boa tarde,

Existe alguma maneira de excluir um periodo sem usar o `BETWEEN`?

```
    x NOT BETWEEN HorFim AND HorIni   
and y NOT BETWEEN HorFim AND HorIni
```

Onde:

```
x = hora inicial digita pelo usuario.
y = hora final digita pelo usuario.
```

tenho que fazer esse sql funcionar sem `BETWEEN`, o problema e que minha hora final(`HorFim`) e menor que a hora inicial(`HorIni`)

Comment: Como estão declaradas as colunas `x` e `y`? A resposta correta depende dessa informação... //  Sem BETWEEN?!  Poderia explicar o motivo?

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Transforme o `DATETIME` em `DATE` para remover a hora e utilize os operadores `maior que` e `menor que`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela
 WHERE (CAST(x AS DATE) < CAST(HorIni AS DATE) OR CAST(x AS DATE) > CAST(HorFim AS DATE))
   AND (CAST(y AS DATE) < CAST(HorIni AS DATE) OR CAST(y AS DATE) > CAST(HorFim AS DATE))
```

Notei também que a ordem do seu `BETWEEN` estava invertida. A condição acima pode ser alterada para:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela
 WHERE CAST(x AS DATE) NOT BETWEEN CAST(HorIni AS DATE) AND CAST(HorFim AS DATE))
   AND CAST(y AS DATE) NOT BETWEEN CAST(HorIni AS DATE) AND CAST(HorFim AS DATE))
```

Comment: O responsável pelo `downvote` pode informar qual o erro na resposta? Somente -1 sem explicação não serve pra nada.